# Which conditions are checked by Petrel in the plug-in manager to see if a plug-in is already installed?

Tags: plugins, ocean, petrel

I created two different plug-ins to load into the plug-in manager in Petrel 2018.
They are coming from the same "code base" even if they are in two different solutions.

So I have two different PIP with different : name, version and all the categories you can find in the plugin.xml.

My problem is that when I load both of them, Petrel (2018) is automatically uninstalling/disabling the first one.

Then, my question is, how does Petrel find that plug-ins are related and that it needs to remove one to install the other one ?
This would allow me to change one of this two plu-ins to be able to have them at the same time in Petrel.

Thank you in advance !

Victor

Comment: @mjwills, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrel_(reservoir_software))  and official site : https://www.software.slb.com/products/petrel

Comment: Perhaps edit the question @xdtTransform?

Answer (score 1):

I would check to make sure that your plug-ins are registered with Petrel correctly by checking the PluginManagerSettings.xml.  Verify that the PluginId property is different between both plugins.

I suspect that the issue is with the Slb.Ocean.Core.IModule.  Are you reusing the same module?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer !

My PluginId properties are differents in PluginManagerSettings.xml but you are right this probably comes from IModule. What should I put in Initialize() method to be sure that I create a new one when I generate a PIP ?

Thank you again !

Victor

Answer (score 0):

You are doing well, I think the problem is the modules load.
You can attach VS before to open the project and debug the flow.

Put breakpoints in

```
Initialize()
Integrate()
WorkspaceOpened()
```

Also, if you are using canned workflows take in account that they "reopen" the project, so take care the methods that load the persistence.

I suppose you are generating 2 .pip, if not you only will have 1 plugin.